# Content generated by Javascript loads outside of its parenthood

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm trying to generate a table with content via Javascript, but I have a problem even when I try to do it statically, like with this very simple example:

```
            document.getElementById("gmaData").innerHTML+='<table border="1">'
            document.getElementById("gmaData").innerHTML+='<tr>'
            document.getElementById("gmaData").innerHTML+='<td>something</td>'
            document.getElementById("gmaData").innerHTML+='</tr>'
            document.getElementById("gmaData").innerHTML+='</table>'
```

But when I run the script, the content of the table is loading outside of the table, and the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags aren't even shown:

```
<div id="gmaData">
    <table border="1"></table>
    something
</div>
```

I have no idea what could be causing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var genHTML = '<table border="1">';
genHTML+='<tr>';
genHTML+='<td>something</td>';
genHTML+='</tr>';
genHTML+='</table>';
document.getElementById("gmaData").innerHTML(genHTML);
```

you can not use string concat with .innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking in markup, but browsers work with object trees (the DOM).

When you read from `innerHTML`, the browser takes the DOM objects inside the element and serializes them to HTML. When you *assign* to `innerHTML`, the browser parses the HTML you give it and creates a DOM structure to match, correcting any malformed content it finds.

The short answer is: Don't use `+=` on `innerHTML` without a really, really good reason. It's unnecessarily expensive (which isn't usually an issue), and more importantly any elements inside the element you do it on will lose their state (including event handlers). And of course, the browser won't let you append the opening of an element and then the end of it *later*.

In your case, you need to assign the HTML for the whole table at once:

```
document.getElementById("gmaData").innerHTML = // Or += if you're really appending
    '<table border="1">' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>something</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '</table>';
```

That sometimes means building up the HTML in a string variable and then assigning when done.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to use += because I want to enumerate an array into my table with a for loop. But the previous answer is working properly, so I make a new variable first with my html content, and I use innerHTML for only that variable

Comment: @definitelynotadev: Yup, that's what I'm saying at the end of the answer.